# Многопоточность чекера прокси Python

Tags: python, requests, proxy, threading

Написал граббер прокси, теперь хочу сделать многопоточный чекер.
Граббер даёт мне список прокси, а через библиотеку `requests` сделаю чекер. Но с библиотекой `threading` незнаком. И не понимаю, как сделать, чтобы потоки одновременно чекали мой список, чтобы не было такого, что один поток закончит раньше или позже другого и чтобы не помешали друг другу.

Comment: Что значит "чтобы потоки одновременно чекали мой список" ? делали запросы на какой то ресурс для проверки прокси? если да то я бы выбрал асинхронный клиент aiohttp

Comment: Ну если не понимаете, то лучше разобраться, а не искать готовую реализацию.[тык](https://habr.com/ru/post/229767/)